# Java application vs. Java applet

Tags: javascript, applet, mapplets

Hey guys I created this pacman game in Java. I would like to put in on my website so people can play on there. However I have never done any applets, nor do I know javascript. Is there a way to automatically convert the project into an applet? Or do I have to code it from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

What is it written in ? If it is in AWT or Swing then you putting it in an Applet is just a packaging issue ( http://java.sun.com/applets/ ).
You can also look at http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/jnlp/ which allows you to run a Java App from a web page
If you are good at Swing you might want to look at GWT (Google Web Toolkit) which is an API very similar to Swing that translates into javascript to run natively on a browser.